# What is the variational characterization of eigenvalues.

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I'm dealing with a nonnegative functional:
$$E(\phi)=\int_{B_R}\left[|\nabla \phi|^2-f^{\prime}(u) \phi^2\right] \geq 0, \text{for any} \  \phi \in C_0^{\infty}\left(B_R\right).$$

The paper told me that since $E(\phi) \geq 0$ for all $\phi \in C_0^{\infty}\left(B_R\right)$, so by variational characterization of eigenvalues, there are a $\lambda_R \geq 0$ and a positive eigenfunction $\Phi_R$ on $B_R$ satisfying Dirichlet boundary conditions on $\partial B_R$ so that
$$
-\Delta \Phi_R-f^{\prime}(u) \Phi_R=\lambda_R \Phi_R .
$$
I want to know what the reference this step needs. If we integrate $E(\phi)$ by part we get:
$$E(\phi)=\int_{B_R}\left[(-\Delta \phi-f^{\prime}(u) \phi)\phi\right] \geq 0, \text{for any} \  \phi \in C_0^{\infty}\left(B_R\right).$$
Then how do we get the eigenvalue and eigenfunction which are both positive?

Comment: It seems that the property $\inf\sigma(L)=\inf_{\|\phi\|=1}\langle L\phi, \phi\rangle$ and the self-adjointness of $L$ are used here. Also, a routine argument: if $\phi$ is an eigenfunction, then $|\phi|$ is also an eigenfunction, and thus we can take a non-negative eigenfunction...   Maybe some more details are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems that the positive eigenvalue is easy to prove but I saw a theorem today which said that the eigenfunction corresponding to the first nonzero eigenvalue of -$\Delta$ is strictly positive or negative, maybe the same for the linear 2nd order partial differential operator. (Theorem4.4 in T.Aubin’s SomeNonlinearProblems in RiemanianGeometry) , I need to check the proof.